# Using GMS security provider APIs from native code in Android

Tags: android, https, android-ndk, openssl, google-play-services

Our native Android library requires HTTPS support. We have ported libcurl and openssl for that purpose and its working well. Recently, there were many Openssl vulnerabilities reported, which requires us to frequently update openssl and release our native library.

The following link recommends using Android's GMS security provider APIs instead of openssl, so that Google will always update GMS with latest security patches.
https://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html

From Application layer (Java), I agree that it is better to use GMS and it is easier too. Is it a right move to use GMS in Android native code?

Comment: Related, see [Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html).